# Update ArrayList for RecyclerView.Adapter from RecyclerView.ViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

In my MainActivity I have something like this:

```
recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, arrayList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
```

To update my RecyclerView, I do: (in MainActivity, too)

```
Item item = new Item();
item.setId(id);
item.setMessage(message);

arrayList.set(position, item);
recyclerAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
```

I want to have a button within every RecyclerView list item which can enable/disable the current entry. Therefore I need to get the current toggle state.

My problem is, how can I update the RecyclerView in MainActivity from within my ViewHolder?
RecyclerView.ViewHolder:

```
public class SetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{//, View.OnLongClickListener{
public ImageView toggle;

public SetViewHolder(View itemView){
    super(itemView);
    toggle = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_main_card_toggle);
    toggle.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == toggle.getId()) {
        int clicked_position = getAdapterPosition();
        //TODO update Item of RecyclerView of MainActivity
    }
}
```

My Recycler.Adapter:

```
public class RulesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SetViewHolder>{
private Activity activity;
List<Item> items = Collections.emptyList();
private OnTapListener onTapListener;
public RulesAdapter(Activity activity, List<Item> items){
    this.activity = activity;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public SetViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rules_list_item,parent,false);
    return new SetViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SetViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.recevied_message.setText(items.get(position).getReceived_message());
    holder.reply_message.setText(items.get(position).getReply_message());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(onTapListener != null){
                onTapListener.OnTapView(position);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

public void setOnTapListener(OnTapListener onTapListener){
    this.onTapListener = onTapListener;
}
```

}

Comment: call `notifyItemChanged ` from `ViewHolder `

Comment: If you add an item to the arrayList in MainActivity and call notifyItemChanged(), I think it wont show in the recyclerview. You may want to update the arrayList used in the adapter

Comment: But how to update the ArrayList from my ViewHolder? How do I access it?

Comment: @Panther I don't understand why you want to update it from viewholder. You can declare the arrayList inside your adapter class public and directly update the list from main Activity and call notifyItemInserted(position); to update the recycler view. I don't know if this is a good practice to declare data set in the adapter class as public. But it surely works

Comment: @Vanna That's actually not my problem. I can only notify about a changed Item, when I changed it. But how to access arrayList, Item or recyclerAdapter in MainActivity from the ViewHolder?

Comment: @Panther if you update the question with your adapter class code I can clarify more

Comment: @NishinRaj I like to have a button inside every RecyclerView list item which can enable/disable an entry. Therefore it needs to get the current toggle status (if it's currently disabled or not).

Comment: @Vanna Can't access, because one is a static context and the other one a non-static context

Comment: @NishinRaj Added RecyclerView.Adapter to post

Comment: @Vanna How to update my ArrayList from within the Adapter?

Comment: @Panther Sorry to ask this now, but what do you really want to do when the button in the row is pressed??? Add an item to recycler view or mark the row as selected or deselected??

Comment: @Vanna I wrote it some lines above: I like to have a button inside every RecyclerView list item which can enable/disable an entry. Therefore it needs to get the current toggle status (if it's currently disabled or not) from within the ViewHolder.

Comment: @Panther try Bob's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an `Interface`.

```
public interface OnRecyclerItemToggleClickListener {

    void onToggleClick(int adapterPosition);
}
```

Implement this in your `adapter`. And pass the adapter instance to the `ViewHolder` through a setter method in the `onCreateViewHolder` callback.

```
public class SetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{//, View.OnLongClickListener{
    public ImageView toggle;
    private OnRecyclerItemToggleClickListener listener;

    public SetViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        toggle = (ImageView) 
        itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_main_card_toggle);
        toggle.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void setRecyclerItemToggleClickListener( OnRecyclerItemToggleClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == toggle.getId()) {
            int clicked_position = getAdapterPosition();


       //TODO update Item of RecyclerView of MainActivity

       listener.onToggleClick(clicked_position);
    }
}
```

In your adapter:

```
@Override
public SetViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rules_list_item,parent,false);
    SetViewHolder holder = new SetViewHolder(view);
    holder.setOnRecyclerItemToggleClickListener(this);
    return holder; 
}

@Override public void onToggleClick(int adapterPosition) {
    // you will get the callback here when the toggle button is clicked.
    // you can update the ArrayList here.
    // Or similarly, call an interface method to Activity.
}
```

And call this `onToggleClick` method from `ViewHolder` when the toggle is clicked. You will get a callback to `adapter`, where you can update the `ArrayList`. Otherwise you can have another similar `Interface` to give callback to `Activity` from the adapter.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you explain it little bit more detailed please? How do I call this onClick method and what to do then?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add a static function and make items static too:

```
public static ArrayList<Items> getAreayList()
{
    return items;
}
```

And get this function in `MainActivity`:

```
onStart()
```